# Compiling Intel I219V ethernet card on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, linux-device-driver, intel, ethernet, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to compile  Intel e1000 drivers for my Intel ethernet card I219V but it failed with error that This driver is not supported on kernal older than 2.4.0.  Do anybody came across this Intel driver issue this is stopped me from working. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why you don’t use the drivers from upstream kernel? In any case it seems you run *make* instead of something like *make -C /usr/src/Linux M=$PWD modules*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up installing a different internet card. There seems to be unresolved issue with Intel drivers for Ubuntu 18. My new card connected without any issues. Totally unacceptable from brand like Intel.